# Can I save Vue output as a Javascript array?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

My Vue code below loads data from a database on page load. I know how to display it in a HTML file by using simple Vue methods. However, I want to save it as a Javascript array. The Javascript array will then be fed into a map (the map requires a Javascript array). Can I do so, and if so how?

```
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#purchase',
  mounted: function() {
    this.allPurchases()
  },
  data: {
    purchases: ""
  },
  methods: {
    allPurchases: function(){

      axios.get('http://localhost:3000/')
      .then(function (response) {
         console.log(response);
         app.purchases = response.data;
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
         console.log(error);
      });
    },
  },

});
```

Comment: The property `response.data` is probably already an array.

Comment: When I do console.log(response.data), I get "Uncaught ReferenceError: response is not defined"

Comment: Response is undefined? - my first thought was everything is fine  and res.data is undefined. As you can add as  many props  to an object as you like(memory). And app  is hoisted and accessed passt declaration/assingment.

Answer (score 2):

You should replace `app.purchases` by `this.purchases` :

```
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#purchase',
  mounted: function() {
    this.allPurchases()
  },
  data() {
    return{
       purchases: []
      }

  },
  methods: {
    allPurchases: function(){

      axios.get('http://localhost:3000/')
      .then( (response) =>{
         console.log(response);
         this.purchases = response.data;
         window.purchases = response.data;//to be used globally
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
         console.log(error);
      });
    },
  },

});
```

Comment: Thanks. But when I call console.log(purchases) in the main HTML file (or even later on in the Javascript file), I still get the error "Uncaught ReferenceErrror: purchases is not defined". What else do I need to do? (Calling purchases only works when I use the console in Chrome's developer tools)

Comment: do you want to use `purchases` outside of Vue instance ? and how do you want to  use it?

Comment: I want to save it as a Javascript array, which will then be fed into a map. (The purchase data contains geocoordinates of the buyers, and the map needs a Javascript array, with each element containing geocoordinates of the buyer)

Comment: `window.purchases = response.data` allows use to use that array globally, you could access it inside the browser console, see the edited answer

Comment: I see. How do I call the variable then? console.log(window.purchases) gives me undefined, and console.log(purchases) gives me an uncaught reference error

Comment: so the problem is in `response.data;`

Comment: Within the axios.get(...).then(...) call, response.data returns an array of more than length 1000. However, outside of the axios call, console.log(response.data) results in an error.

Answer (score 0):

Simply change `app.purchases =` to `this.purchases =`